# Gigabyte motherboard M.2 B450 DS3H specification grammar

Tags: motherboard, ssd

I'm newbie with pc-building and I found the [gigabyte's page](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10#sp) of the product this:

> 1 x M.2 connector (Socket 3, M key, type 2242/2260/2280/22110 SATA and PCIe 3.0 x4/x2 SSD support)
>   * Supports only M.2 SATA SSDs when using an AMD Athlon™ 200-series/ 7th Generation A-series or Athlon™ APU.

And now my question is:
Does that note mean that I can only use  M.2 SATA when I have an Athlon and if I have ryzen only PCI-E? Or maybe that it doesn't support PCI-E with Athlon and with ryzen both?
I have an [M.2(B+M) SSD](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07BMXS6SH/?tag=pcp06-21) that should support both, but I'm not sure if it will be compatible with a [ryzen 2600X](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07B428V2L/?tag=pcp06-21).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hardware Recs! In general, our affiliate site [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) is better equipped to handle questions regarding technical support and/or compatibility. If your intention was to ask for a M.2 SSD upgrade, you should re-edit your question to minimize chance of closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed an ambiguous wording, but it definitly means that Athlon / 7th gen APU will only allow SATA mode and others will allow both.

So you won't be limited to SATA with your A1000 with a 2600X.